# iPhone MPMoviePlayerController : download files while streaming en play them locally

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, m3u

I've m3u8 file with all the TS files. MPMoviePlayerController play them fine via http request on the streaming server. But I'd like to get the files locally in order to play them again later without any connection.

I managed to download m3u8 file and all the TS files locally on my device, I edited m3u8 files to point to local .ts instead of http ones, but I can't read them from this emplacement.
(VLC can do it well)

Is there a way to download the segments while playing (to avoid 2 downloads) and then to play them locally with MPMoviePlayerController or else.

Comment: good question - afaik, MPMoviePlayerController is not able to play m3u8 stream from a local URL (filesystem) as the networking part of MPMoviePlayerController will always try to negotiate the "right" bandwidth/profile from the m3u8 snippet - that part does not seem to work locally and becomes a showstopper. If that is correct (as I assume), then you will have to provide and alternative file on your server -> MP4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.m3u8 is Apple HTTP Live Streaming, right? I think what you're trying to do simply goes against the design of that technology. You should expose the original file and allow it to be downloaded.

From what I understand, it's in the design of streaming that you don't get explicit access to the pieces in order to put them back together. For instance, Netflix uses streaming via Silverlight, and one of the benefits (to Netflix) is that it protects the data from being saved as if it were downloaded. Also, since HTTP Live Streaming allows a stream to switch bitrates on the fly, it's designed such that each time slice can be encoded at any number of bitrates, and none of them is canonical.

In theory, there might be a way to collect all the slices for a particular bitrate and re-encode them into a single video. But Apple's playback APIs are not going to give you that opportunity.

Instead of HTTP Live Streaming, consider progressive download. Just serve the original video file (transcode it to something the iPhone likes if necessary). If your server is configured properly, the playback APIs will do small requests to get particular chunks of the file, rather than the whole thing in one go, and it's a close second to proper streaming. I wish I could find where I read about this so I could give the proper name for it. Amazon S3 is set up to serve this way, if you need a quick solution.

But beware, [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) say,

> If your app delivers video over
>   cellular networks, and the video
>   exceeds either 10 minutes duration or
>   5 MB of data in a five minute period,
>   you are required to use HTTP Live
>   Streaming. (Progressive download may
>   be used for smaller clips.)

Comment: thanks, I'm doomed to download the mp4. It 'll be 2 downloads, one full mp4 files and on other segmented file depending on client wishs