# iOS - Video Streaming, Prevent Video from being downloaded or saved locally

Tags: ios, ios5, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Is there any way to play Video Streaming via URL in iOS native App which can not be downloaded or saved locally. I want to let the user watch video but he should not be able to download or save video locally (via 3rd party downloader apps).

Is above case can be possible in MPMoviePlayerController, MPMoviePlayerViewController or WebViewController?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible via MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourLink];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
Are you sure that any 3rd party Downloader App will not be able to download this video within MPMoviePlayerViewController?

There are many apps available on iTunes which can be used to download the video which is being played in the device.
 for example : http://thinkios.com/24681/download-universal-video-downloader-app-from-cydia-to-download-videos-from-any-ios-app/ etc

Comment: when video is being played then those downloader apps show an alert to download that video....

Comment: It depends on how do you do the streaming. Please check the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420311/iphone-mpmovieplayercontroller-download-files-while-streaming-en-play-them-loc

Comment: I just want to play video via url just like you have mentioned in the Answer.  The link you have shared is opposite to my case. I want to disable or prevent video downloading when video is being played via Url in MBMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: Yes, and in the comment it's been said that "For instance, Netflix uses streaming via Silverlight, and one of the benefits (to Netflix) is that it protects the data from being saved as if it were downloaded."

Comment: Ok this is going to be confusing now :-|
I was interested to know whether it is possible or not to disable/prevent video downloading in iOS App using native controllers of iOS (WebView, MPMoviePlayerViewController etc).

Comment: So the code which you have added in answer is not explaining the actual question, but only explains how to play video streaming from url? right?

Comment: The code I provided lets you do the streaming. For the other part of your question where I referred to another topic, preventing the stream video from downloading rellies on how you present your stream video. It is not impossible to download the video but in most cases your best choice is to make it harder to be reached such as embedding link into an HTML an presenting it in this way.